# No access to CreationDate metadata using PyPDF2

Tags: pypdf

From the documentation [PyPDF2 Metadata](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/user/metadata.html)

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")

meta = reader.metadata

print(len(reader.pages))

# All of the following could be None!
print(meta.author)
print(meta.creator)
print(meta.producer)
print(meta.subject)
print(meta.title)
```

Yet I don't see any access "meta.creationDate" to the value associated to the key '/CreationDate' in meta.

Why is this?

I have tried print(meta.creationDate) to see what would occur, and I got the error "AttributeError: 'DocumentInformation' object has no attribute 'creationDate'" despite it being a key in the metadata dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute is called creation_date, not creationDate:

https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/DocumentInformation.html#pypdf.DocumentInformation.creation_date

Also you should use pypdf and not PyPDF2. I'm the maintainer of both.

Comment: Thank you! Can you point me to the discussion that highlights why you say "...use pypdf and not PyPDF2."?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/